# Matrix with rows and columns labeled with equations

Tags: matrices

I want to label the rows and columns with quantum states as $\ket{n_1l_1m_1}$.
To save space I tried to rotate these states by using

`\rotatebox{80}{\ket{n_1l_1m_1}}`

but this is not possible - how can I rotate math equations?

To make it more clear I want to replace the H (and also the Y and D) in the image
by 90 degree rotatet quantum ket states

[image]

Comment: What you want is not very clear. Could you post a sketch?

Comment: Maybe I can solve ma problem when I know how to rotate math equations?

Comment: as for any box, reenter math `\rotatebox{80}{$\ket{n_1l_1m_1}$}`

Comment: if you tried, you would have seen thats not working

Answer (score 4):

With `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}


$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,code-for-first-row=\rotate]
& |n_1l_1m_1\rangle& |n_1l_1m_1\rangle& |n_1l_1m_1\rangle\\ 
|n_1l_1m_1\rangle & 0.8 & 0.2 & 0 \\
|n_1l_1m_1\rangle& 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 \\
|n_1l_1m_1\rangle& 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

By default, Overleaf uses an old version of  `nicematrix`. However, you can provide it the newest version of `nicematrix.sty`. Go [here](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty). At the top of the page, you have the latest version of `nicematrix`. It's the revision 56256. You do a right click on `download` and you save the file under the name `nicematrix.sty`. Put that file next to your file in your Overleaf project (buttom `import` next to `new file`).

Comment: ```Undefined control sequence.``` is the error

Comment: Maybe you don't have the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation.

Comment: I am using overleaf

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: @F.Pantigny While you are at it: What about giving `\rotate` an option to set an angle for the rotation? I'm asking something and have no clue, whether it would be more or less easy to implement. So maybe you better ignore this comment.

Comment: Usually, when people want to rotate an element by an angle of 45° in a tabular, they want an overlapping behaviour for the resulting box (because they don't want to increase the width of the column). It would be necessary to add yet another option for the command `\rotate` to allow that overlapping... I wonder what would be the best syntax...

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative could be using `blkarray` with a combination of `braket` packages to define the command `\ket` and the `graphicx` package to use the rotation of `\ket{n_1l_1m_1}` with the macro `\def\rotbra#1{\rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\rotbra#1{\rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
 & \rotbra{\ket{n_1l_1m_1}} & \rotbra{\ket{n_1l_1m_1}} & \rotbra{\ket{n_1l_1m_1}}\\
\begin{block}{c(ccc)}
  \ket{n_1l_1m_1} & .8  & .2 & 0 &\\
  \ket{n_1l_1m_1} & .3 & .4 & .3 &\\
  \ket{n_1l_1m_1} & .2  & .1 & .7 &\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]
\end{document}
```

This is the output of the code:

[image]